Subtracting value from pivot table (only when the data is available)
The data in my pivot table changes every week. Sometimes the value for certain data will not be available during certain week and available in other week. For now I had to manually check the data and adjust the formula when the data is not available. Is there any formula to make condition that if the data from pivot table is not available, no need to substrate the value

Can you show us  a simple sample. What does the certain data that not be available and be available look like? What are results that you want?
